# ActionBarSherlock overflow listview

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

After integrating the ActionBarSherlock in my android app I noticed that the dropdown menu that drops when the user hits the overflow button differs between 2.* and 4.*.

I have successfully customize this dropdown menu for 2.* with the right colours, but the dropdown menu in 4.* is displayed with white color andblack text and nothing that I do seems to modify this menu.

Do I need to do anything special to customize this dropdown menu in 4.*? it is even possible?

Thanks

Comment: If the dropdown menu has XML, then just could load a different one or use `res/layout-vAPIVERSION/` folder

Comment: I have done a similar thing by overriding some values in the styles an themes. But they only seem to affect the 2.* devices. 4.* devices seems to use the native menu.

Comment: yeah, Still could not managed to fix the issue.

Comment: Please add your theme and styles xml to the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a style for ABS, you must be sure to also include the proper Android tags. E.g.

Not just

```
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
```

But

```
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
```

The former only controls ABS, and the library uses the standard Action Bar on 4.x.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it makes sense and I tried it, but still did not fix the problem and the overflow menus are still generated by the OS on 4.*+ and thus ignoring the customization